# reading an objective C encoded object into a java class

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, serialization, encode

I am writing a client server iPhone app. The server is J2EE based. 
I need to communicate the state of my client object (objective C) to the server. It is possible (and feasible) to say encode the objective C object, send the bytes to the J2EE server through a socket and create a Java object out of this stream. If so, can you kindly point me to a starting point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: great thanks everyone. I get the idea that encoding in one language and decoding in another is not feasible really. i will perhaps go the xml way for the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything is possible, but that does not make it feasible. Except the technical difficulties these interfaces tend over time to create a lot of management headaches, example when one or both sides perform an upgrade.

I would seriously consider using some encoding to some platform neutral format like [protobuf,](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) [thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/), JSON, XML or similar.

Comment: Especially if you use something like Xstream on the server and equivalent on the client, you can effectively pass Java/ObjC objects back and forth with an extra step of calling "toString()"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it would be easier to serialize the Objective-C object to XML, JSON, or another text-based representation and ingest and unmarshal that in Java. To return it, reverse the process.

Answer (score 1):

There are myriad ways to skin this cat.  If you are using J2EE, you might even consider using a standard means of communication rather than rolling your own.  For example, you could use  a webservice, REST, etc.  Objectice-C has good support for HTTP connections and it is fairly trivial to create an XML or JSON payload. [SudzC](http://sudzc.com) is a great tool for creating a client proxy from WSDL.

Here are a few tools on the Objective-C side:

[json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)
[SudzC](http://sudzc.com)